# EF Core, INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface on my EF POCOs. I am using newtonsoft to serialize my models to JSON. Currently my object is using [JsonProperty] attributes to tell newtonsoft what to serialize. When I implement this interface I will have properties with private backing fields. Do I place the [JsonProperty] attribute on the properties or on the backing fields?

Comment: I would prefer the properties, but you don't need to use any attributes. The serializer will figure it out for you if your naming reasonable. Also, that sounds like a lot of behavior for a POCO...

Comment: The attributes are needed since the Original property setters are private, but there are other issues preventing me from moving forward anyways, but thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

I would put it on the property personally. In my example i have an Order POCO with a list LineItems that hangs off of it.

```
[DataMember]
[JsonProperty(TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects)]
public List<LineItem> LineItems { get; set; }
```